# How to solve "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not 'float') to str" with this particular code?

Tags: python, math, typeerror

I'm new to coding/Python so any help is greatly appreciated. I'm trying to figure out how to calculate sales tax r but I can't figure out how to do is.

```
import math

class userEntry:
    userName = input("Enter Customer Name: ")
    userQuantityPurchased = int(input("Enter Quantity Purchased: "))
    userPrice = int(input("Enter Price per Unit: "))

class taxCalculator:
    stateTax = .09
    salesAmount = float(str(userEntry.userQuantityPurchased*userEntry.userPrice))
    stateCalculator = str(salesAmount*stateTax)

class programOutput:
    print("------------------------------")
    print("Here is your Net Sale!")
    print("------------------------------")
    print("Customer Name:  " + userEntry.userName)
    print("Sales Amount: " + taxCalculator.salesAmount)
    print("State Tax: " + taxCalculator.stateTax)
```

Comment: `print("Sales Amount:", taxCalculator.salesAmount)`. Same for the next line.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. In this case, the problem is obvious, but in the future, please provide a [mre] including how you use the classes. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to convert the float to str:

```
print("Sales Amount: " + str(taxCalculator.salesAmount))
```

But actually, it's easier to have `print` do it for you, along with the joining:

```
print("Customer Name:", userEntry.userName)
print("Sales Amount:", taxCalculator.salesAmount)
print("State Tax:", taxCalculator.stateTax)
```

P.S. This usage of classes is highly non-idiomatic, and I would recommend avoiding it unless it's required for a class or something. And there are other problems with your code I won't go into.

Comment: Thank you so very much. The answer was right in my face but it takes someone like you to thankfully make it obvious lol. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Steven Hindsight is 20/20, lol. Welcome! :)

Comment: also, if you want to judge my code I would greatly appreciate it aswell. I am trying to learn as much as I can.

Comment: @Steven Well, the biggest problems are that `math` and `stateCalculator` are not used and `stateCalculator` shouldn't be converted to `str`. There are some subtler problems too, like the wrong casing of class names, and pointless conversion `float(str())` since it's already an int. If you wanted more explanation, you could post on [codereview.se] and lmk, but you'd need to provide complete code.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are coming from a java/C background and can answer your question. You are trying to concatenate a str type with a float. Also the making sales amount a str first and then a float is redundant and importing the math library here is not needed. I made you an example class with some common naming conventions that follow the 'Zen of Python' and the PEP 8 guidelines.

```
class SalesTax:
    def __init__(self):
        # class variables
        self.user_name = None
        self.user_quantity_purchased = None
        self.user_price = None
        self.state_tax = None
        self.sales_amount = None
        self.calculated_state = None

    def ask_user(self):
        self.user_name = input("Enter Customer Name: ")
        self.user_quantity_purchased = int(input("Enter Quantity Purchased: "))
        self.user_price = int(input("Enter Price per Unit: "))

    def calculate_tax(self, state_tax: float):
        self.state_tax = state_tax
        self.sales_amount = float(self.user_quantity_purchased * self.user_price) * 
            (1 + self.state_tax)

    def print_result(self):
        print("------------------------------")
        print("Here is your Net Sale!")
        print("------------------------------")

        print("Customer Name:  " + self.user_name)
        print("Sales Amount: " + str(self.sales_amount))
        print("State Tax: " + str(self.state_tax))

example = SalesTax()
example.ask_user()
example.calculate_tax(0.09)
example.print_result()
```

Comment: I appreciate the thorough explanation! and yes, you guessed right. Thanks!